# Размещение application.properties на внешем ресурсе + SpingBoot

Tags: spring-boot

Я слышал, что можно настроить обращение к application.properties, который находится на отдельном ресурсе , чем развернутое веб-приложение.

Таки образом, мы в конфигурационных файла приложения только указывает адрес, по которому можно приложению обращаться на внешний ресурс и получать **application.properties** - **только для чтения**.

Таки образом, нельзя будет отредактировать application.properties, группе техников, которые должны заниматься только развертыванием приложения.

Как это можно сделать, знает ли кто пример, где это может быть  описано?

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на проект Spring Cloud Config [официальная документация](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/)

При использовании данного проекта вам необходимо будет:

1. Создать и развернуть отдельное приложение конфиг-сервера
2. Во всех существующих сервисах добавить зависимость на spring cloud
3. Во все компоненты добавить файл конфигураций bootstrap.properties, в котором прописать url до сервера конфигураций

С этого момента конфигурации будут раздаваться для всех сервисов в режиме read-only автоматически при старте приложений и при разворачивании сервисов не потребуется заботиться о настройках.

При этом вы можете хранить настройки не только в общедоступном гит репозитории, но и можете инициализировать локальный репозиторий на vm с конфиг-сервером.